# First Application on IPad: where to set the button event?

Tags: ipad

I have 4 years experience on DotNet, not much.

I now learned developing for IPad.

I made a new project and opened the MainWindow.xib by double click in the interface builder. Not I put there a label, a textbox and a button.

But how to make the button event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kovu, "Paull" already told you.  Please understand that I am not being short, cruel or otherwise negative when I suggest that you read more about XCode and MVC.  In order to program for iPhoneOS you really need to understand the MVC method of programming.  If you don't know what those initials stand for, it means you really **should** read more before you try your hand at it.  iPhoneOS is so totally different than `.net` that you need to understand basics.

I suggest Erica Sadun's book:  (her website is: [iPhone Developer's Cookbook](http://ericasadun.com/)) or a great starter article at: [BIT-101](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1969).

It will get you up and going VERY quickly (inside of a week for me) and does not skimp on the basics. TRUST ME--if you do not understand the basics from the very beginning you will be lost when it comes to developing for iPad (or even iPhone/iPod).  The iPad is such a very different beast than Windows .net that you will be surprised the change you will have to go through (for the better) in order to grasp it.

On the positive side, you will become a better programmer.  Using the MVC method is really freeing in a lot of ways.  Event-driven programming is a wonder to behold when done right, and believe me, Apple did it right (for the most part) in the iPhoneOS.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the getting started guides in the Documentation window of Xcode (under Help).

You just create an IBAction in your controller, and drag a connection from the button to the controller.

Comment: Tried this, I see this in a podcast, but there is no IBAction window

Comment: That's why you need the read the guides; this isn't .NET, and IB isn't a code generator.  A proper explanation would take too long here.

Comment: I read a lot in the last time about it, and in IPhone View its there but in the IPad Window not!

Comment: You'll need to explain what you think isn't there.  Hint: there's no such thing as an "IBAction window".

Comment: I don't find anything, I look the whole evening, please tell me how to do, please